# Where do you store Realm's Database files on ios?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Where do you store Realm's Database files on ios?

1. Documents / RealmDataBaseFile.realm
2. Libary / RealmDataBaseFile.realm
3. Library / AppName / RealmDataBaseFile.realm
4. Libary / cache / dbfile <- This is not allowed because it is deleted
   periodically.

I think the third is the best. (I created the app for the first time ^^;;;)

Would it be okay with 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your First option
Documents / RealmDataBaseFile.realm
Can be access by users via iTunes

Your second option
that Library folder can't be accessed by users
that's why it is right option to save database 
so user can't modify the database

In third option you create sub folder in Library folder
and it's good for managing also other files if you want to store in library folder

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I chose the third option. Create and save a subfolder in the Library folder. Is this a good idea?

Comment: Thank you. It's a great answer. I create a subfolder of the Library and manage the photo and RealmDatabase files in that folder.